# How can I install & launch Google Chrome?

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

I want to log in to my Google Chrome browser.

I downloaded the .deb from Google but it would not install. I came to Ask Ubuntu and read that I should download gdebi installer. I did that but I didn't/don't know what else to do.

Then someone said I should install Chromium and I did so.

Now what?

Comment: and since you say you're a novice, you should probably install chromium `sudo apt-get install chromium`.

Comment: What is the prefix sudo apt? Is there a learning program for this operating system because I am a new user?

Comment: Oops, should have said `sudo apt install chromium-browser`, sudo is for execution of privileged instruction. But you can do it with the graphical interface, run "Software" then search for "chromium web browser"

Comment: Thank you so much. I am very familiar with where I would type the run command in the other operating system I was using but I am not familiar with where I would type that command using this operating system?

Comment: CTRL+SHIFT+T will open a terminal, then type the command.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you please tell me what chromium is?

Comment: Chromium is the open source browser that Chrome is based on. I am not sure why installing it was recommended to you - perhaps because it's easy to install software from repositories - but it was recommended (I assume) as an alternative to Chrome. @pim in future, if you have an answer, please [post it in the answer section](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments/2377), because comments can't be easily improved or reviewed by others.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the `.deb` file from Google's website, and make note of where you save it.
2. Open a terminal window and `cd` into the directory containing the `.deb` file. So for example, if you downloaded it to your Downloads folder, do `cd ~/Downloads`.
3. Once you've `cd`ed into the directory, run these commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo dpkg -i nameOfChromeFile.deb
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

Chrome should then be good to go!

Comment: I seem to have downloaded it twice but I am not able to locate where the file was saved. Shall I download again? Can you further explain Steps 2 & 3? I

Comment: @QUEWilliams You can open a terminal with `CTRL+ALT+T`. Once you have located the file, you can right click it to open the properties window which will show you the full path of the directory in which it is located.

Comment: Thank you so much! Any thing else you can share to help me get more familiar with my transition to this new operating system?

Comment: @QUEWilliams Many things which are done through the GUI in Windows are done through the command line in Linux. I suggest you seek out some tutorials on using the Linux command line, especially since the GUI will differ from distribution to distribution.

Comment: @ Android Dev Thank you. I figured such.  I tried to cheat by asking seasoned users and failed due to my lack of  the basic knowledge.  I just wanted to catch up to lost productivity due to my laptop breaking.  I can't  wait to dive into it! Where would I find the most comprehensive tutorial for dummies?